# limit physical memory in linux

Tags: linux

I wanna to test a program which need a system with **512MB** of RAM. But my system has 1GB RAM. This is not possible to detach RAM physically from Motherboard and I don't want to use VM or docker. How can I limit or decrease physical system memory in Linux by commands so that `free -m` and `top` commands show the 512MB size for memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mem` kernel parameter will allow you to limit the maximum amount of physical RAM visible to the kernel.

```
kernel=... mem=512M ...
```

Comment: I edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="mem=512M"` in file `/etc/default/grub` and issue the command `update-grub`. Then it works. Thanks.